# How to get the probability of each vector belonging to each cluster?

Tags: nltk

I use the following code to create clusters. I would like to get the probability of each vector belonging to each cluster. How to do this?

```
import numpy as np
from nltk import cluster
from nltk.cluster import euclidean_distance

vectors = [np.array(f) for f in [[3, 3], [1, 2], [4, 2], [4, 0]]]

clusterer = cluster.KMeansClusterer(2, euclidean_distance)
clusters = clusterer.cluster(vectors, assign_clusters=True, trace=False)
```

Comment: Kmeans does not compute probabilities; the equivalent would be the distance to the cluster centroids. If you want probabilities, you can for example use a [Gaussian model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html).

Comment: @patrick do you mean I can use sklearn.mixture.GMM to do clustering and get membership probability? If so, could you please offer a code example?  I tried to use nltk.cluster.EMClusterer, but it doesn't converge for my dataset.

Comment: I've added it in an answer below for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn import mixture
model = mixture.GMM(n_components=4)
model.fit(dataset) 
model.score_samples(dataset)
```

this returns, acc to [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html)

> Posterior probabilities of each mixture component for each observation.

But of course this won't help if the Clustering doesn't converge for your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! mixture.GMM converges on my dataset. Does this means something wrong with nltk.cluster.EMClusterer's EM implementation?

Comment: I don't think that it necessarily means that. Acc to the [docs](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/cluster/em.html) the NLTK implementation uses a Gaussian model as well, so it should be very similiar. I would hazard to guess that the default settings differ between the models. "Converging" also doesn't mean much; if the model converges on a useless / unstructured model, that doesn't help much. In both cases you'll have to fiddle with the settings to see what gives you good results.

Comment: EM algorithm requires initial means. It seems mixture.GMM doesn't take input of initial means. Does this mean mixture.GMM automatically create initial means on behalf of users?

Comment: @kokoma If by EM you mean [expectation maximization] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation–maximization_algorithm) algorithms --  the GMM is an EM algorithm. It uses Gaussian distributions in an EM framework. And yes, the scikit.learn implementation just sets the means automatically at initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about:

1. the assignments kmeans made to vectors from your `vectors` variable or
2. the assignment of a new vector to an existing cluster?

### 1. The K-means assignments

Simply print the `clusters` variables. If you see [0, 0, 1, 1], then it means [3, 3] and [1, 2] (the first two) got assigned to the cluster 0, and [4, 2] and [4, 0] (the last two) to the cluster 1. There's no probability here.

### 2. Assigning a new vector to an existing cluster

Since you're using KMeans, you first need to know what is the centroid of each cluster. The nltk API says this is a private information : the interesting variable (`_means`) is prefixed by an underscore. The variable could change in the future, but you can still get the value if you want to.

The NLTK algorithm is randomized, so you will get different centroids each time. As I said before, you can see the assignments with `print(clusters)`. You can see the centroids with `print(clusterer._means)`. Let's say you got the assignment [0, 0, 1, 1] with centroids [2, 2.5] and [4, 1]. A new vector (say [1, 2]) would be assigned to an existing cluster by using the closest cluster. Again, it makes little sense to talk about probability here. You could get scores by using distance for all clusters and then using softmax to get to probabilities if you really wanted to.

Comment: clusterer.classification_probdist(vectors[0]) gives me <ProbDist with 2 samples>. I don't know how to decode this returned object. What does this method return? The probability 0 or 1 for each vector? If I run cluster.EMClusterer, will this function returns some probability values other than 0 or 1?